# Anchoring controls in windows forms vertically to resize properly

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I'm trying arrange controls in a WinForms application so that they resize properly when the form size is changed. Every time I try to resize the form the second label gets overlapped. Obviously I'm not getting the trick here. Can anyone please advice on how to set anchoring in a layout like mine.

[image: Window layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can solve this by anchoring, but it won't look nice ... if you use only anchors, then you'll have to decide for one of those big text boxes to resize with the window ...

try out the `TableLayoutPanel`.

it's a standard control shipped with the framework, and it will most likely solve your problem AND look nice in the end ...